# Decompressing using GZipStream

Tags: c#-4.0, zip, gzipstream

I have a zipped up file within a resource and am attempting to decompress this zip file. However I keep getting this exception...?

The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

```
byte[] zipFile = HTMLEditor.ZipTest.HTMLEditor;

string output = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

var bigStreamOut = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

//Decompress                
using (var bigStream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(zipFile), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    bigStream.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);
}
```

Any ideas anyone? Currently using .Net 4.0 and don't really want to use external libraries?

Comment: Do you understand that gzip and zip are different things?

Comment: I had an idea, just can't figure out how to decompress the zip file within the resource?

Comment: In .NET 4.5 you can use `ZipFile`, but I don't know of anything in .NET 4. It's possible there are bits of WPF that are capable of handling zip files, but I suspect the cleanest way would either be to require .NET 4.5 instead, or to use an external library. Certainly `GZipStream` is *not* going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem with bigStream.CopyTo(bigStreamOut);

```
 byte[] step = new byte[16]; //Instead of 16 can put any 2^x
int readCount;

do
        {
            readCount = bigStream.Read(step, 0, step.Length);
            bigStreamOut.Write(step, 0, readCount);
        } while (readCount > 0);
        bigStream.Close();
```